# How do I combine my game.exe and "media" folder into one .exe file?

Tags: installation, media, exe

I've been searching for this for ages but no solutions. It's simple. I've created a C++ game. So I have a game.exe and next to it I have a folder named "media" from where the game takes all the images and sounds it needs. Now obviously when other people play the game I don't want them to see the media folder. I want to combine them into one .exe file. Can someone PLEASE explain to me how to do this like I'm five?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve your goal:

> 1. Simple add the content of your folder as resources to your project (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3sk7e6b.aspx)
> 2. Create a resource-DLL ([How do I create a resource dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219975/how-do-i-create-a-resource-dll)) and link it to your project

In both cases the sounds and bitmaps will be not visible (binary) - that is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah this is what I want, but the part where I said explain it to me like I'm five. That part is important. I have no idea what to do with this information. I've been reading documentations following on from this link that just start going into circles and never come to the point where it plainly says: do this, then do this, etc. Also I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express which I believe has some restrictions when it comes to adding resources to my project. If there is some beginner tutorial on how to make a DLL or anything I would be grateful.

Comment: OK, Visual Studio 2008 Express - in this case I would do it like case one (Simple add the content of your folder as resources to your project), with DLL it will be complicated. So open the Resource Editor of VS and add your pictures/sounds like this: http://www.mpgh.net/forum/31-c-c-programming/130465-adding-using-resources-visual-studios-express.html

Comment: Looks cool, but the first link in the tutorial is broken and in my prevous reserach I have come upon this broken link 3 times already. Seems to be one of the key resources for learning this... and it's gone.

EDIT: I may have found the original http://suite101.com/article/vc-express-external-res-editor-a21264

But since I know nothing about the subject, I can't be sure if this is it.

Comment: I was not aware that the Express Version don't have any Resource Editor :( But the thing you found looks nice - try it! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's not so obvious to hide the media folder, games often have a lot of folders.
In c# you can add pictures as resources to the project, so it gets embedded into the exe. There must be something like this in c++.